# How I can pass the results obtained by a query with group_concat(distinct) in another query?

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have a table named university_schools which contains all the courses records of each university and a table university_main_campus which contains records of all the universities. I want all the courses names from another table called 'courses'(which contains all the details including course_name, course_slug etc) of each course within that university.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM courses 
WHERE course_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT course_id) AS STR_CRSE_IDS 
                    FROM `university_schools` WHERE univ_id = '2289')
```

I am getting only the first record whereas there should be 11 records.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,

```
SELECT courses.*, b.STR_CRSE_IDS FROM courses INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT course_id as STR_CRSE_IDS FROM university_schools WHERE univ_id = '2289') AS b ON courses.course_id = b.STR_CRSE_IDS
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to build custom string with `GROUP_CONCAT`. You could use simple `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id  
                    FROM university_schools WHERE univ_id = '2289');
```

Please note that with `GROUP_CONCAT` you will get something like:

```
IN ('1,2,3,4')
--and I guess you expect:
IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: of course I know that. I am not after that auto incremented,primary column of the university_schools table I am after that column which resembles the course id from courses table i.e; if B.Tech is a course and the course_id is '1' then in the university_schools table it will be '1' value in the course_id column which is not auto incremented neither a primary key. I want to get all the course ids from this table and then I want to hit that comma separated string of all the unique course ids into the main query "SELECT * FROM courses".